# REST API $expand issues

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list that has a look-up column into another list.  Ex: **B** list has a look-up column called 'navB' that is a look-up into a column in list **A**.  The name of that column in list A is called 'navA'.

When I look at the api, I see an ID called 'navBId'.

I try to expand it like this but it doesn't work

`/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('B')/items?$select=navBId&expand=navA`

I get an error when I do this.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "navB" is the column that is *in* list B but is a *lookup to* list A, you want something like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('B')/items?$select=navB/Title,navB/Id,navB/OtherColumn&$expand=navB
```

You want to **select** which fields from the *lookup list* that you want returned, then **expand** the lookup column *in this list*.

If you want the value of the "navA" column from the *other* list, it would be

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('B')/items?$select=navB/navA&$expand=navB
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you sir

Answer (score 6):

As @Dylan said, when using `$expand` endpoint you need to mention the column name from `List B` in `$expand` and then you can select the column from `List A` in `$select` query like below:

```
siteUrl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('B')/items?$select=navB/navA,navB/Title,navB/Id&$expand=navB
```

Adding to this answer,

**You cannot expand and select all the columns** from `List A` as lookup columns does not support all the column types.

**Supported Column Types**:

- Single line of text
- Choice (single value)
- Number
- Currency
- Date and Time
- Lookup (single value)
- Person or Group (single value)

**Unsupported Column Types**:

- Multiple lines of text
- Choice (multi-valued)
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Lookup (multi-valued)
- Person or Group (multi-valued)
- Yes/No

**Source**:

1. [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) - Check `Creating unique columns` section.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the added information. Very helpful

Comment: Welcome. Keep using this platform to ask your questions related to SharePoint.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273151/dynamic-sharepoint-master-page-navigation-but-scope-issue-for-navigation-drop-do